# Box-shadow only in the middle of a <DIV>

Tags: styles, stylesheet, css

What I am trying to achieve is a **shadow ONLY in the middle** of a div. What I have now is:

```
<body style="background-color: #ccc;">
<div style="padding: 30px; 
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 20px #000;">
    Some text in the box</div>
</body>
```

**Which looks like (#1):**

[image]

**But I want to achieve (#2):**

[image]

**Question A:** Is it possible to **achieve #2 using only CSS**?

**Question B:** If yes to Question A, how should #2 be modified to achieve the effect only on the top and the bottom, **leaving the sides shadowed all the way from left to right** (#3)?

[image]

Clarification: The intent is to use a 50% shadow that shows up only in the middle of a div, but I CANNOT change any HTML, only CSS. Also, The code posted here is oversimplified. There are several elements inside the div, including images. I cannot change their BG.

Comment: Why not just change the background-color?
I don't see what you're trying to achieve here... You can give a box an inner shadow if you would like...
box-shadow:         inset 0 0 10px #000000;

Comment: with backgrounds you can set the origin to the content box with background-origin: content-box;, but the box-shadow is always attached to the border box so it will not work. You can sort of get what you want, if you fudge it enough with :first-line (if your text is only one line long) but that is not ideal, as it is the width of the text without any hacks. http://jsfiddle.net/zZnQu/

Comment: @DavidKnag, because I can only change CSS, not create another div, which is bigger than the area I want shadowed PLUS the effect is supposed to be a shadow over a background image. So I can't change bg-color. And `inset` is already being used, though I want the shadow to be in the **middle** of the box, not on the inside of its edges.

Comment: http://css3generator.com/

Comment: What if you used gradient backgrounds on the div?

Comment: @DavidKnag I don't want to shade the entire DIV, and I cannot insert a new DIV. CSS only, no HTML changes.

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved your #3 using this html:

```
<body>
    <div id="shadow">Some text in the box</div>
</body>
```

and this css:

```
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
    background-color: #ccc;
}

div#shadow {
    margin-top:20px;
    padding: 15px 30px;
    background-color: #000;
    color:white;
}
```

you can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/quPB5/

---

Edit:

Here is only the modified CSS:

```
<body style="background-color: #ccc;margin: 0;padding:0;"><div style="margin-top:20px;padding: 15px 30px;background-color: #000;color:white;">Some text in the box</div></body>
```

Comment: I cannot change the HTML, only CSS. But it seems that you achieved #2, not #3 anyways.

Comment: i didn't change your html i modified the css. I'll show it your way right now. and in your 3rd image, it shows the black going from left to right, which i did.

Comment: You have created a div ID. Besides, I cannot change the existing DIV's margin or padding as it would affect other items in the composition.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "box-sizing" to move the padding and borders etc, inside the div and in this way - keep the div size despite changes in padding or shadow. In this case I have box-sizing on the wildcard, *

I put it on everything, but you can just put it on the elements you want as well.

Also add inset to your shadow.

HTML

```
<div class="box box-shadow">inset shadow</div>
```

CSS

```
* { -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; }

/* this moves padding and borders and such inside the div instead of outside */

.box {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: .5em;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.1);
}

.box-shadow {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 50px 5px #f06; /* Android 2.3+, iOS 4.0.2-4.2, Safari 3-4 */
          box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 50px 5px #f06; /* Chrome 6+, Firefox 4+, IE 9+, iOS 5+, Opera 10.50+ */
}
```

[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/seSAL/) is a jsfiddle with it in action:

As far as your last question I'm a little unsure of what you want. shadow just on top and bottom? That would be cool... could use some pseudo elements maybe --- ? ? ?

Comment: I will take a look at it. I want to achieve the desired effect, which would be light top/bottow and shadow flush from left/right.

Comment: Wait, I see LIGHT on the inside and DARK on the outside. That's a normal shadow. I want the opposite...

Comment: I guess I didn't read your question thoroughly enough. Sorry about that. You could put a border: 20px solid transparent; maybe... I have updated the fiddle above to reflect this option as well.

Comment: Sorry. Still confused. I don't understand. Are you going to use a box shadow with a fade? I think I was going in the wrong direction.

Comment: If you give me a link or something to somewhere you have seen the desired effect, maybe I will be able to understand. The black boxes are throwing me off.